How to run an AppIntent in onTapGesture?
I have a SwiftUI button that needs to:

Run an AppIntent when tapped: right now I'm using using Button(intent: MyIntent(), label: { ... })
Remove the visual blink when tapped
Run a different function on long-press

2 and 3 can be achieved by replacing the button with its label, and putting the AppIntent in an .onTapGesture { } on the label instead. But putting the AppIntent in .onTapGesture doesn't work. Is it possible to run an AppIntent from within onTapGesture?
If not, how can I disable the blink and add an .onLongPressGesture to a button?
